# Can't boot linux off a dvd

Tags: linux, boot, dvd

I am trying to install Linux on my PC. I burned the ISO to a bootable disk. I changed the BIOS settings to CD/DVD drive priority. When I put the disk in, it says "booting from cd...". It then just boots into original OS (Windows XP).

Comment: You should provide more information, about how did you burn the disk, BIOS type, Linux distro...

Comment: @wizardsambolton Probably you burned it wrong or you chosen the wrong image (wrong architecture) or something else. You can use Bochs emulator on Windows to see if the DVD boots correctly.

Comment: See also: [Computer won't boot from CD/DVD drive](http://superuser.com/q/109817/87805)